Getting filesize, speed, downloaded bytes from Unity's webrequest
I have 3 scripts namely a MenuManager, NetworkManager and a custom HttpsClient script. When a buton is clicked it calles a function in the menumanager that calls the networkmanager to download some data from the server (custom backend server - Asp.net server). I want the HttpClient to report back the file size, download speed and the total downloaded bytes to the networkmanager then the networkmanager passes the info back to the MenuManager so I can update the UI.
MenuManager:
private async Task DownloadPlayerInfo()
{
    LoginPanal?.SetActive(false);
    RegisterPanal?.SetActive(false);
    await networkManager.DownloadPlayerInfo();
    //Pass a progress callback to the DownloadPlayerInfo method
    /*networkManager.DownloadPlayerInfo((progress, speed, fileSize, bytesDownloaded) =>
    {
        // Update UI with download progress, speed, download size, and amount downloaded
        UpdateDownloadProgress(progress, speed, fileSize, bytesDownloaded);
    });*/
}

private void UpdateDownloadProgress(float progress, float downloadSpeed, long fileSize, ulong bytesDownloaded)
{
    float speed = 0f;
    string abriviation = "B/s";

    if (downloadSpeed >= 1024 * 1024) // If speed is more than 1 MB/s
    {
        speed = downloadSpeed / (1024 * 1024);
        abriviation = "MB/s";
    }
    else if (downloadSpeed >= 1024) // If speed is more than 1 KB/s
    {
        speed = downloadSpeed / 1024;
        abriviation = "KB/s";
    }
    else
    {
        speed = downloadSpeed;
        abriviation = "B/s";
    }

    DownloadInfoText.text = $"{speed:F1} {abriviation} Progress: {progress:F2}% " +
                            $"({bytesDownloaded / (1024 * 1024):F1}MB / {fileSize / (1024 * 1024)}MB) " +
                            $"- {progress:F2}%";
}

NetworkManager:
public async Task DownloadPlayerInfo()
{
    var payload = new UserInfoRequest() { UID = UID };
    await HttpClient.PostWithProgress<UserInfoResponse>(userInfoEndpoint, payload, PlayerToken);
}

HttpClient:
public static async Task<T> PostWithProgress<T>(string endpoint, object payload, string header = null)
{

    var postRequest = CreateRequest(endpoint, RequestType.POST, payload);


    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
        AttachHeader(postRequest, "Bearer ", header);

    postRequest.SendWebRequest();
    long fileSize = long.Parse(postRequest.GetResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
    while (!postRequest.isDone)
    {

        // Calculate progress, downloaded bytes, and download speed
        float progress = postRequest.downloadProgress;
        ulong bytesDownloaded = postRequest.downloadedBytes;
        float downloadSpeed = bytesDownloaded / Time.deltaTime; // Bytes per second

        // Report progress and speed during download
        Debug.Log($"Size: {fileSize} Progress: {progress * 100}% - Speed: {downloadSpeed} bytes/s");



        await Task.Delay(10);
    }

    if (postRequest.isNetworkError || string.IsNullOrEmpty(postRequest.downloadHandler.text))
    {
        string errorMessage = "";
        if (!postRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            errorMessage = postRequest.isNetworkError ? "Network Error" :
                                 string.IsNullOrEmpty(postRequest.downloadHandler.text) ? "Empty Response" :
                                 postRequest.error ?? "Test null";
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Internal Server Error";
        }
        GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ErrorLogger>(true).LogError(errorMessage, "Error: " + errorMessage);
        return default;
    }

    try
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(postRequest.downloadHandler.text);
    }
    catch
    {
        GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ErrorLogger>(true).LogError(postRequest.downloadHandler.text, postRequest.downloadHandler.text);
        return default;
    }
}

I tried this with the other scripts modified to fit this but no luck
public async Task DownloadPlayerInfo(Action<float, float, long, ulong> progressCallback)
{
    UserInfoRequest req = new UserInfoRequest() { UID = UID };
    var (response, progress, speed, fileSize, bytesDownloaded) = await HttpClient.PostWithProgress<UserInfoResponse>(userInfoEndpoint, req, PlayerToken);

    
    progressCallback?.Invoke(progress, speed, fileSize, bytesDownloaded);

    
    HandleUserInfoResponse(response);
}


httpclient is not the best way to do this in unity, they made their own which plays better of unitywebrequest..

I am afraid it is not going to work the way you coded it. Basically you are awaiting until your task is done before you send it back to the client. So your progress is lost. I see at least two solutions here:

You could use polling. Create two api methods: one is sending the request DownloadPlayerInfo(userId) in fire and forget manner and the second one is getting the progress periodically GetDownloadProgress(userId). This way the server has to keep and recalculate/update the progress state. Check this: Asp.net core file uploads reporting progress back to the front end

If you want the way you wrote it, you have to use websockets (Using WebSockets with ASP.NET Web API) or signalr or some similar technology. Plain web-services are usually simple, stupid and stateless.


